# working extra hours and pay

Tags: salary

It's my belief that if a person is at working, doing work, they should get paid for it. What's the appropriate response when someone suggests that you should stay at work longer to finish a problem? I would probably be ok with doing this if I know I'm getting paid for it, how should I phrase the question? If the person was talking about staying at work late, just because other people do, how should I decline?

Comment: What's in your employment contract? Do you get paid overtime?  If no, then you'll have to decide for yourself if not working late will impact on your job.

Comment: What country? If USA, exempt or non-exempt?

Answer (score 2):

The appropriate response is that study after study has shown that working about 40 hours per week is the most productive way to work. Not just the most productive per hour, but the most productive per week.

Another quote by a guy who wrote a huge book about software development for Microsoft Press (can't remember his name): "You can make people stay at work for 80 hours a week. You can't make them work more than 40 hours".

Many problems are solved by going home, having a nice dinner, having a shower before you go to bed, and wham - there is the idea in your mind how to solve the problem. Sometimes you need a shower in the morning as well :-) Much more effective than staying at work longer when you are already tired.

Now if your company ever *really* feels the need that you should work more hours per week, suggest that they should book you into a hotel at the closest possible distance to work. If they accept, that demonstrates that they *really* need you and don't just try to extract more work for free.